# ViewControllerのパーツのStackViewの内部のbuttonに制約をかけたい

Tags: swift, uikit

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementingACustomControl.html
上記のチュートリアルを実施していて、`Add Buttons to the View`という場所をやっていたところである疑問が出ました。
ViewControllerからStackViewで生成されるButtonに対して制約をかけたい場合はどうすればいいのでしょうか？

【状況】
チュートリアルではStackBiew(RatingControl.swift)でその内部のbuttonに制約をかけていますが、これではViewControllerで扱っているViewをanchorとして参照できません。そこで私はdelegateでやればいいのかな？と思い以下のように実装しました。

・RatingControl.swift

```
import UIKit

protocol RatingControlDelegate: class {
    func setConstraint(of target: UIView)
}

class RatingControl: UIStackView {
    //MARK: Parameters
    var ratingControlDelegate: RatingControlDelegate?
    
    //MARK: Initialization
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupButtons()
    }
    
    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupButtons()
    }
    
    //MARK: Private Methods
    private func setupButtons() {
        // Create the button
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        print("In RatingControl -- Button Address = \(ObjectIdentifier(button).hashValue)")
        
        // Add the button to the stack
        addArrangedSubview(button)
        
        // Add constraints
        ratingControlDelegate?.setConstraint(of: button)
    }
}
```

・ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, RatingControlDelegate {
    
    // MARK: Properties
...
    @IBOutlet weak var rating: RatingControl!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        // Handle the rating button constraint for auto layout.
        rating.ratingControlDelegate = self
    }
    
...
    
    //MARK: RatingControlDelegate
    func setConstraint(of target: UIView) {
        print("In ViewController -- Button Address = \(ObjectIdentifier(target).hashValue)")
        target.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        target.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0).isActive = true
        target.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0).isActive = true
        target.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    }
}
```

この状態で実行したらconstraintは適用されずMain.storyboardで配置してある場所に表示されました。またprint文の結果も以下のようになっておりViewController.swiftのsetConstraint(of:)が呼ばれていない気がします。

```
In RatingControl -- Button Address = -6568234602690583333
```

【聞きたいこと】

1. delegateしたはずのViewController.swiftのsetConstraintが呼ばれていないのは何故でしょうか？
2. そもそもこのようなパターンはどう実装するのが正しいのでしょうか？Classは参照型だったと思いますので、この方法だと実現できないのかと思っています。

以上よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> delegateしたはずのViewController.swiftのsetConstraintが呼ばれていないのは何故でしょうか？

`RatingControl`がインスタンス化される時(つまり`init(frame:)`または`init(coder:)`が呼ばれる時)には、まだ`ratingControlDelegate`は設定されていませんので、`nil`です。したがって、その中で`ratingControlDelegate?.〜`という呼び出しをしても静かに無視されるだけです。

> そもそもこのようなパターンはどう実装するのが正しいのでしょうか？

そもそもこのようなパターンは作らないのが正しい実装です。`UIStackView`と言うのは内部に配置されたviewの間に自動的に制約を設定することにより、縦並び・横並びを簡単に行わせることを目的としたもので、`UIStackView`内部のview(ボタンなども含めて)と`UIStackView`が置かれている外側のviewとの間に制約を付けることはしませんし、無理やり制約をつけても、`UIStackView`が自動的に付ける制約との間に矛盾が生じて、正しいレイアウトにならない場合が多いです。

`UIStackView`内部のレイアウトは`UIStackView`に任せて、`UIStackView`そのものと外部のviewの間に制約を設定してください。